# Blueprism Application Modeller showing Launch instead of Identify when spying

Tags: blueprism

I am using BluePrism v6.1.0 and I am trying to identify elements from a launched application in Application Modeller. (I used the Windows application type in the modeler configuration) 
From some tutorials I saw, the launch button changes to Identify button after the app is launched, however, mine is still showing "Launch". Please see screenshot below
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCsTe.png)

Comment: Did you launched your application from BP or was it already running?

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch the application from the application modeller, not on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Windows 10, the built in applications are use differently than normal in windows 7. Here is how you can add the code to make it work with your system [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFXVS.png). Also for future applications use this code in Windows Power Shell to get information about the application you wanted to work with in Window 10 : "Get-AppxPackage"

Answer (score 0):

Not fully explained here but this can also mean not only is the app not launched but blueprism can't "see" the app is launched. Two ways to solve this so close the application and relaunch it then it will change to identify, OR you can attach the current instance of the object to the running application.

Either way the outcome is you're making blueprism see the active application so it will change the launch to an identify option.

Edit: watch out as well, if you connect your application to blue prism and then detach it blue prism will no longer see the running application hence will revert the identify option into a launch option.